How can I fix this simple error using pdf2image?
Beginner here, not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Simple Code:
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

images = convert_from_path('sample.pdf', 500, poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-24.07.0\Library\bin')

for i in range(len(images)):
    images[i].save('page' + str(i) + '.jpg', 'JPEG')

Error:
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'sample.pdf': No error.

Originally, the module coundn't get a page count because I did not have a poppler. After I figured out the poppler, I thought it would work, but it still does not.

You can't use bare backslashes like that.  Backslashes are escape codes in Python strings  You either need to (1) make it a raw string, as in poppler_path=r'C"\Program..., or (2) double all the backslashes, or (3) convert them to forward slashes.

Are you SURE that "sample.pdf" is in the current directory when you run this script?  Note that the current directory is NOT the same as the directory that contains the script.  How, exactly, are you running this?

Avoid ambiguity by providing an absolute path to sample.pdf and make sure you have permission to open it

Usually, I have this problem because the path to the file is not defined correctly. That is why the lib is unable to open and read pdf. Try to give the correct path by copying it from the file: "copy path" or "copy relative path".
